# How to run a Racket program without output being quoted?

Tags: string, output, scheme, racket, quotation-marks

I have a basic Racket program:

**hello.rkt**:

```
(write "Hello, World!")
```

When I run it with `racket -f hello.rkt`, I get the following output:

```
"Hello, World!"
```

Is there a special compiler flag, or special version of "write/print" that removes the quotes from string output, so that it shows:

```
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`write`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._write%29%29) function is the dual to [`read`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29): it outputs (or at least attempts to output) datums that could be [`read`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29) back in to produce the original value. In my experiences, it is not often terribly useful even for that purpose, but it can be helpful when you’re debugging.

For actual output, the function you want is [`display`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._display%29%29). This outputs the actual data itself to the output port, not a formatted representation of it.

---

For completeness, Racket has an additional printing function, called [`print`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print%29%29). Unlike [`display`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._display%29%29) and [`write`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._write%29%29), [`print`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print%29%29) is explicitly designed to be used for debugging. Its output can be customized by a variety of different parameters, so the output format is uses it not necessarily predictable, and it shouldn’t be used for anything other than debugging. For that purpose, though, it’s quite useful.

Answer (score 5):

Use `display` instead of `write`.